# gcloud beta container backup-restore backup-plans update/create supports the --paused option but not --resume/unpaused

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm using `gcloud beta container backup-restore` to script my backup setup.
When I disable an environment I would like to simply pause the backup process before deleting all backups.
But it seems once paused I can't get it back to resume backing up with the gcloud CLI.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/add-on/backup-for-gke/how-to/backup-plan#pause_a_backup_schedule
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/backup-restore/backup-plans/update

`Resume` only works on the GCP console. Haven't found an option for the gcloud CLI.

Comment: Does anyone know if someone can contribute to gcloud cli?
I didn't find it on github or in the google documentation